# Java: File#reName() successfully rename the file, but the file object still reference the old name

Tags: java

I experienced a strange behavior from Java

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
file.reName(new File("test1.txt"));
```

The file successfully rename from `test.txt` to `test1.txt`, but if I do

```
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath()); //This return test.txt
```

Is this expected? And what is a clean way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. `File` objects are immutable, and simply represent a filename.

You can think of it like this: a `File` object is a *reference to a file*, not the file itself.

This behaviour can actually be useful - for example, imagine that you are moving a previous version of a file out of the way to avoid overwriting it (i.e. to create a backup copy). If you rename `foo1.txt` to `foo1.bak`, then the original `File` variable that contained `foo1.txt` will still contain it, and can be used to open a `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: So to refresh the file reference, I need to `File file = new File("test1.txt")` again? Correct?

Comment: You should not specify the type again unless you want to create a new variable. So it should be `file = new File ("test1.txt")`

Comment: (Note `File` objects aren't that immutable. You can subclass them and override the methods to do all sorts of evil.)

Comment: Ambiguity of language. Objects whose class is `java.io.File` are immutable. But good point!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is expected. A File object is an abstraction of a path with respect to the underlying file system. It need not correspond to an existing file. The `renameTo` method moves the underlying file if it exists and if it is moveable. However, that does not change the path represented by the File object.

Comment: So to refresh the file reference, I need to `File file = new File("test1.txt")` again? Correct?

Comment: @Harry - yes. As Robin said, a `File` object instance is immutable. If you want one that references the moved file, you need to create a new one.